# How to install a 32-bit node.js(8.5.0) into a 64-bit ubuntu(17.0)?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I've downloaded 32-bit、64-bit node binaries of v8.5. Currently I also have a 64-bit ubuntu os(v17.0). I tried `./bin/node` both on 64-bit binaries and 32-bit binaries, and 64-bit was working fine but 32-bit node binary returns `bash: ./node: No such file or directory`.

So how do I run 32-bit node on 64-bit a linux system?

You may ask why I'm doing this, because there are some very old `.so` library which is 32-bit, I can't get this library working with `node-ffi` with 64-bit node, so sadly I have to install a 32-bit node.

Also, I've tried `nvm install 8.5.0 32`, it downloads x64 sadly. And I just realize this only works in windows with this `nvm-windows`, which indicates there is a way to install a 32-bit node on a 64-bit OS?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at[this article](https://www.unixmen.com/enable-32-bit-support-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10-greater/) 
First you'll need to enable 32-bit support:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo     apt -get update
```

The article I linked to then recommends `apt-get dist-upgrade`, but I'm not actually sure that will do much for you.

Then you'll need to install the libraries that the 32-bit version of node uses.

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

will install the base set of libraries that all applications need in 32-bit mode.

```
sudo apt-get install libares2:i386 libicu57:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386
```

should get you to a point where running ./node gives a useful error pointing to a specific library that you need to install so that Node can run.

Comment: When I'm trying to install libc6:i386 it says it depends on libgcc1:i386, so I tried to install libgcc1:i386 first and it says it depends on libc6:i386...

Comment: Try installing both at the same time then.

Comment: Yes I did so, and now my ubuntu system has become a brick... LOL

Answer (score -2):

I've tried: sudo apt install nodejs
And it worked.

Comment: ... and how do you make sure it's 32-bit?